# How do I configure the vue input component to my specifications

Tags: vue.js, input, vuejs3

I am attempting to make a vue component, a checkbox with a dot and some text.
But I am having difficulties understanding how I parse values to it from where I am using it.

My Template with the checkbox.

```
 <template>
      <label class="dot-checkbox" :for="id">
        <input
          :name="name"
          :id="id"
          type="checkbox"
          v-model="this.isChecked"
          ref="element"
          @blur="$emit('blur', $event)"
          :class="{ 'v-input': 1, 'v-input--invalid': v?.$error }"
          @change="e => this.isChecked = e.target.checked"
          :checked="shouldBeChecked"
        >
        <span :class="this.isChecked ? 'active' : ''"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></span>
        <span class="text-element">{{ this.text }}</span>
      </label>
    </template>
```

My script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "",
  isChecked: false,
  text: "",
  id: "",
  data: () => ({
    checkedVals: ['bar'] // TODO: get actual checked value
  }),
  methods: {
    shouldBeChecked(val) {
      return this.checkedVals.includes(val)
    },
    updateVals(e) {
      let isChecked = e.target.checked
      let val = e.target.value

      if (isChecked) {
        this.checkedVals.push(val)
      } else {
        this.checkVals.splice(this.checkedVals.indexOf(val), 1)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and in my view I try to use it like this.

```
<form-dot-checkbox
                :name = "column_name"
                :id = "column_name"
                :isChecked = "false"
                :for = "column_name"
                :text = "Navn"
            >

            </form-dot-checkbox>
```

I would like to be able to do the following.

- Set the id and name of it.
- if it is checked or not
- when checked add an active class to the first span (not text-element)
- And when I check it, I should be able to tell it which function to run.

I am having difficulty understanding the relationship there is between where I use the component and how I access the properties in the component it self..

Hopefully someone can help, and I can get some sort of understanding out of it..

I have ofcourse tried google, forums and the documentation.

Comment: There is no `this.` in template. `v-model="this.isChecked"` should be `v-model="isChecked"`. Same goes for all the other places where you use `this.` in template. Make this change and see if you still have errors. If you do, update the question so it's relevant to the errors you're seeing. A *runnable* [mcve] would be really helpful for anyone trying to offer assistance.

Comment: I'd also suggest re-wording your request. State in clear what you want to happen vs what is actually happening. *"understanding the relationship there is between where I use the component and how I access the properties in the component"* is a vague and unmeasurable request which, in essence, is an open invitation to emitting subjective opinions and interpretations, rather than fact based statements. In short, your request is currently borderline *off-topic* for being broad and vague. Please make it more precise and clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `props` to pass your data to your component:

```
export default {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isChecked: {
      type: Boolean,
    ,
    text: {
      type: String,
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  data: () => ({
    checkedVals: ['bar'] // TODO: get actual checked value
  }),
  methods: {
    shouldBeChecked(val) {
      return checkedVals.includes(val)
    },
    updateVals(e) {
      let isChecked = e.target.checked
      let val = e.target.value

      if (isChecked) {
        checkedVals.push(val)
      } else {
        checkVals.splice(this.checkedVals.indexOf(val), 1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[see the doc on vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html)

there is no need of `this` in vue3 component.

```
    <template>
      <label class="dot-checkbox" :for="id">
        <input
          :name="name"
          :id="id"
          type="checkbox"
          v-model="isChecked"
          ref="element"
          @blur="$emit('blur', $event)"
          :class="{ 'v-input': 1, 'v-input--invalid': v?.$error }"
          @change="e => isChecked = e.target.checked"
        >
        <span :class="isChecked ? 'active' : ''"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></span>
        <span class="text-element">{{ text }}</span>
      </label>
    </template>
```

You also forgot to declare your `emit` event when you use `@blur="$emit('blur', $event)"`: [see doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#event-arguments)

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read througfully the following `Vue.js` [Documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html) sections:

1. [Form Input Bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html)
2. [Components Basics](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html)
3. Components In-Depth: [Props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html)
4. Components In-Depth: [Component v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html)

Also check the the Vue [Tutorial](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-1)

- Step 5. [Form Bindings](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-5)
- Step 11. [Components](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-11)
- Step 12. [Props](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-12)

And Vue [Examples](https://vuejs.org/examples/#hello-world)